# Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.replace (<anonymous>)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Keeps getting error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` when calling this function on the development mode. But if i build it, it runs perfectly. I've also tried adding reactStrictMode: false in next.config.js but still the same result on dev mode.

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState<any[]>([])
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)
    const [haveMore, setHaveMore] = useState(false)
    const [isShowMoreLoading, setIsShowMoreLoading] = useState(false)

    const handleShowMore = async () => {
        setIsShowMoreLoading(true)

        const result = await fetchPosts(pageNumber, 2);
        if (result) {
            setPosts(prevPosts => prevPosts.concat(result.posts));
            setHaveMore(result.isNext);
        }

        setIsShowMoreLoading(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleShowMore()
    }, [pageNumber])
```

here are the button

```
<Button
    onClick={() => setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1)}>
    Click to show more
</Button>
```

and the fetchPosts function

```
export async function fetchPosts(pageNumber = 1, pageSize = 20) {
    try {
        connectToDB();

        const skipAmount = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize

        const postQuery = Thread
            .find({ parentId: { $in: [null, undefined] } })
            .sort({ createdAt: 'desc' })
            .skip(skipAmount)
            .limit(pageSize)
            .populate({ path: 'author', model: User })
            .populate({
                path: 'children',
                populate: {
                    path: 'author',
                    model: User,
                    select: "_id name parentId image"
                }
            })
            .populate({
                path: "community",
                model: Community,
                select: "_id id name image",
            })

        const posts = await postQuery.exec()

        const totalPostsCount = await Thread.countDocuments({ parentId: { $in: [null, undefined] } })

        const isNext = totalPostsCount > skipAmount + posts.length

        return { posts, isNext }

    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(`Error fetchPosts ${error.message}`)

    }
}
```

I googled it but it says that it occurs due to recursion. But why does the error shows up only on development. It's kind of annoying to run build everytime i change something.

Comment: What exactly is in `// code ...`??

Comment: I've updated the code